# Angular JS - Select field not loading content when editing

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a select field in AngularJs inside a ng-repeat:

**HTML:**

```
<span ng-repeat="lang in vm.formState.languageList track by $index">
    <select ng-model="lang" ng-options="lang.name for lang in vm.langs">
        <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
    </select>
 </span>
```

**Controller:**

```
this.langs = [
      {name: "English", id: "en"},
      {name: "German", id: "ge"},
      {name: "Spanish", id: "sp"},
      {name: "French", id: "fr"},
      ...
];
```

*formState.languageList* is an array containing each lang object select by user in creation form, e.g. formState.languageList = [{name: "English", id: "en"}, {name: "Spanish", id: "sp"}]

My problem is: when I'm editing the form, I want the form fields (input, checkboxes, selects...) filled with current information. Everything works fine, except for select field.

How can I get this select fields loaded when editing the form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are facing the famous dot problem.
You can confirm it by change the ng-model to use $parent

```
  ng-model="$parent.lang"
```

why it is not working is because ng-repeat is isolate scope directive.

the better way to solve it is use `controllerAs` syntax

Comment: I'm really using controllerAs syntax. $parent didn't solve my problem. @entre

Comment: but then if you are using controller-as, why use ng-model is not having dot in it e.g. `controllAs.lang`, do u have plunker